# Defining propositional atoms without set theory

Tags: logic

> In this
> section we also fix a set $A$ whose elements will be called propositional atoms (or
> just atoms), such that no propositional connective is an atom
>
> [Chapter-2, Lou van den Dries, Mathematical Logic
> (Math 570)](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Evddries/main.pdf)

This was in a book which was supposed to be a introduction to logic. My question is, how can the word "set" be used here when set theory is not defined yet?

Comment: This question seems very specific to this text.

Comment: Do you have any better books? @lulu

Comment: Replace "set" with collection.

Comment: I was not protesting the text, with which I am unfamiliar, just saying that nobody unfamiliar with that particular text can hope to say much.  So, it's not really a math question.  That said:  one has to use *some* words and every choice might be problematic.  You protest "sets" but what about "elements" or "fix"and so on?  Is the author using any set-theoretic notions?  could you substitute "collection" or whatever?

Comment: Are numbers already defined? If no, why use them to number chapters?

Comment: But then you have to define a collection... @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Generally an interesting question, I would say! But, as indicated by the others, this is pointing to philosophical matters, as far as I understand: How/Why is *any* theoretical exposition sufficiently 'rigorous' or 'build from scratch' (for you)? Still, I think, in some sense, you are right: The book is maybe not very 'reflective' in its use of language. The set theory book from Potter (2004) calls itself to be a 'critical introduction'. Maybe you'd like this more. I personally also enjoy st.openlogicproject.org, which is for free and to my understanding reflective at least to some degree.

Comment: You have to start somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

On page 5, van den Dries says

> The following little book is a good place to read about these matters. (It also contains an axiomatic treatment of set theory starting from
> scratch.)
>
> Halmos, P. R., **Naive set theory**, New York, Springer, 1974
>
> In an axiomatic treatment of set theory as in the book by Halmos all
> assertions about sets below are proved from a few simple axioms. In
> such a treatment the notion of set itself is left undefined, but the
> axioms about sets are suggested by thinking of a set as a collection
> of mathematical objects, called its elements or members.

And Halmos says on page 1

> One thing that the development will not include is a definition of
> sets. The situation is analogous to the familiar axiomatic approach to
> elementary geometry. That approach does not offer a definition of
> points and lines; instead it describes what it is that one can do with
> those objects. The semi-axiomatic point of view adopted here assumes
> that the reader has the ordinary, human, intuitive (and frequently
> erroneous) understanding of what sets are; the purpose of the
> exposition is to delineate some of the many things that one can
> correctly do with them.

Hence, one is expected to start with a pragmatical conception of set, admitting it formally as a primitive (i.e., undefined) term, thereafter, develop and sharpen it through one's study of set theory, using it according to a specified syntax and set up semantic relations with other mathematical domains of objects.

This divergence between the defined and the undefined is related to the divergence between proof and truth.

Answer (score 1):

Logic, broadly speaking, is a branch of mathematics which studies various aspects of the meta-language of mathematics, which is used in all branches. In order for such a theory to be a candidate to be used as a foundation for all of mathematics (or whatever), first we have to study it using mathematical tools, such as sets.

It is very easy to confuse these two aspects. Studying a formal language to get results about it, and using it as a foundation. Totally different things.